# iOS - Swift How to close/remove subview when in tapped outside?

Tags: ios, swift

Here's how I have connected the subview

[image: Here's how I have connected the subview]

```
@IBOutlet var PopupView: UIView!

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.view.addSubview(PopupView)
    PopupView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height/3)
}
```

also, I have enabled user interaction for the view.
Still touches Began function does not work
I need touchesBegan to dismiss/remove the subview

```
@objc func dismissPopUpview(){
    PopupView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: From where `dismissPopUpview` is being called?

Comment: you can add tapGestureRecognizer to your view, or simply add button to your view you want to dismiss

Comment: @FaysalAhmed `override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        guard let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) else { return }
        if !PopUpView.frame.contains(location) {
            dismissPopUpview()
        }else {
            print("Tapped inside the view")
        }
    }`

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I do not intend on adding a button for that

Comment: @FaysalAhmed in order to do that I need TapRecognizer or touches began event.

Comment: @BhanuThapliyal Add an invisible button behind your `PopupView `, and use the action for it to remove the view, it's the easiest way

Comment: @Tj3n YUP I did that but was looking for cleaner alternative

Comment: I have already enabled user interaction for the view